# Types for req and res in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, express

[In this demo](https://repl.it/@OleErsoy/Repl-Medium-Typescript-Express) I'm attempting to use the DefintelyTyped [`Response`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L101) and [`Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L98) types for the `req, res` parameters.  However this does not compile:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    res.send('Hello Express Lovers!');
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
```

The error is:

```
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:4:9 - error TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type'Response'.
```

Comment: Which error does it not compile with? Did you import those types?

Comment: Yes - `@types/express`

Comment: Installing a package just makes the types available to import. The existence of a local package does not import types on its own.

Comment: Repl didn't bark at me so I thought they were auto imported ... Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should import Express the TypeScript way so its types (in `@types/express`) come along, allowing the types of `req` and `res` to be inferred from `app.get`:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Express Lovers!');
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
```

[updated demo](https://repl.it/repls/SpatialRewardingNetworking)

If you wanted to type them explicitly anyway, you would have to import the types:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('Hello Express Lovers!');
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
```

Comment: use `esModuleInterop` and you can write `import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'`. Much nicer.

Comment: hi,how do you know the req's type is Request and res's type is Response?I look up all **.d.ts file in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express,and did not get any hint